# Is injecting user input dependency class to menu class appropriate?

Tags: architecture, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, user-interface

I am currently designing classes for the User Interface (UI) of my application. When defining the interface of a class `MenuTabSelector` I faced a design decision of whether I should inject the user input as a dependency.

## My Current Implementation

`MenuTabSelector` is responsible for selecting and maintaing the state of one of the tabs in the menu of my project.

Its interface I initially tried is something like this:

```cs
public MenuTabSelector(UserInput); // constructor
public MenuTab GetCurrentTab(); // state accessor
```

And, for example, one of the use cases of this class is something like this:

```cs
UserInput userInput = new UserInput();
MenuTabSelector menuTabSelector = new MenuTabSelector(userInput);

userInput.PressRight();
userInput.PressRight();
userInput.PressRight();

Assert.IsTrue(menuTabSelector.GetCurrentTab() == UserTab.Inventory);
```

---

## The Problem

After writing that case, I asked myself if it was a smell that my `MenuTabSelector` was changing its state because of events in one of its dependencies.

---

## Alternative Implementation

For instance, I could implement it without the `UserInput` dependency, by using something like this:

```cs
public MenuTabSelector(); // constructor
public void SelectNextTab(); // command
public MenuTab GetCurrentTab(); // state accessor
```

With the same use case written like this:

```cs
MenuTabSelector menuTabSelector = new MenuTabSelector();

menuTabSelector.SelectNextTab();
menuTabSelector.SelectNextTab();
menuTabSelector.SelectNextTab();

Assert.IsTrue(menuTabSelector.GetCurrentTab() == UserTab.Inventory);
```

And with that, the connection between `UserInput` and `MenuTabSelector` could done in a higher level of abstraction, with this such as

```cs
// App
// ...
userInput.OnPressRight.Subscribe(menuTabSelector.SelectNextTab); // event subscription
// ...
```

---

## My Question:

Is is a smell to implement a component that changes its state because of events in one of its injected dependencies? Does it change anything if it is a user input (an UI) class? If so, what problems should I expect because of this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, if it wouldn't be about user input, the first approach is not necessarily bad:

- You [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) an object at construction,
- You [observe](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) the injected object
- And you react on the observed object's change of state

If done properly, you have the desired behavior, and loose coupling.

But in the context of your problem, this perfectly decent design might not be the most appropriate:

> I asked myself if it was a smell that my MenuTabSelector was changing
>   its state because of **events** in one of its dependencies

The case of user interface events raises several questions.  How do you make sure that the event receiver isthe right receiver of the input ?  How will other objects that depend on user input receive their input in due time ?  And finally, how to make it flexible, for example allow the right press button of the keyboard doing one thing, and some mouse command do a similar thing ?

It is possible that your UserInput and current design already have taken these aspects into consideration. But your second approach seems a lot more flexible and promising:

- First it allows the menu builder to be different from the using class.
- Second, it lets flexibility about which event should trigger which action.
- Finally, it let the using class decide to which source the menu shall listen.  The using class could then, if necessary, act as a [mediator](https://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) between different UI components (e.g. waiting text box also needing to process the right press).

Another alternative could be to handle the received events, and process them with a [chain of responsibility](https://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html).  The chain lets you have several potential receivers for the event.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer with good references to known design patterns. Reading more about the [mediator](https://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) pattern made me believe that this is indeed a case where this should be applied. In fact, UI composition is the example for the mediator pattern in the book [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612).

Comment: @Albuquerque Thank you for your feedback: this additional information will be useful for other readers confronted to similar questions

Comment: Should the content and title of the question be edited to better reflect that "we are dealing with UI"? Perhaps a title such as `Is it a bad practice to have an object state respond to user input events as dependencies?` or even "`Should user input be an injected dependency`?". Initially I was unaware that I was in fact asking that, but after reading your answer perhaps it would be clearer. In fact, I think some of the downvotes were because of that.

Comment: @Albuquerque good idea! “user input class” to avoid ambiguity with the user input content ?  Downvotes were probably triggered by “bad practice” which might encourage opinion oriented questions (“yes it’s bad” vs “no it’s good”).

Comment: Changed title and introduction of question by rephrasing "Is it a bad practice" and by adding the fact that this is a question about user input. Thanks for the guidance. Side note rant: Hell... many "good practices" advice are based on concrete cases and are more "experience guidelines" than "opinion based". If anything, sometimes the answer  "There are no guidelines for that. This is opinion based." can be really valuable on assuring that you are not overthinking something because of lack of experience. E.g. One could think that choosing the name of a variable is "opinion based".